# How to prove that any rational linear combination of u and v will also be transcendent?

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers, transcendence-theory

Let u a algebraic number and v a transcendent number, so any rational linear combination of u and v will also be transcendent. How to prove it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x:=\alpha u+\beta v$ with $\alpha,\beta$ rational (and $\beta\not=0$). If $x$ is not transcendental, it would be algebraic. But then also $v=\frac1\beta(x-\alpha u)$ is algebraic, a contradiction.